# How can I get a running sum for a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I've got following data I'm reading from a file:

```
data = {{{2013, 1, 11}, 4},
   {{2013, 1, 12}, 1},
   {{2013, 1, 14}, 1},
   {{2013, 1, 16}, 2},
   {{2013, 1, 18}, 1},
   {{2013, 1, 19}, -1, 16},
   {{2013, 1, 20}, 2},
   {{2013, 1, 21}, 2}
   };
```

(notice that list elements may have an extra item.)
Now I want a similar datelist with each time the accumulated sum (ignoring possible third elements after a data item, like the 16 in the example). Procedurally I'd do something like this:

```
tally = 0;
datelisttally = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[data],
  tally = tally + data[[i]][[2]]; 
  datelisttally = Append[datelisttally, {data[[i]][[1]], tally}]; i++];
DateListPlot[datelisttally, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}, Joined -> True]
```

but I'd like to learn the best way to do this with functional programming, best being the fastest. (The file may hold several thousands of items.)

**update**
I've benchmarked the 3 current solutions, and these are the results (list length = 1 million elements, averaged over 50 runs):

- Szabolcs's: **0.33 s**
- PlatoManiac's: 0.54 s
- Leonid's: 3.33 s

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One (not functional) possibility out of many:

```
dataacc = data;
dataacc[[All, 2]] = Accumulate[data[[All, 2]]]
```

This will keep the third elements.  If you want those removed, you can start with `dataacc = data[[All, 1 ;; 2]];`

I didn't benchmark, but I expect this to be fast.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the `Accumulate` function. (which reminds me of what a fellow student of mine said: "programming is like magic. It's easy once you know the magic words.")

Comment: @stevenvh Before `Accumulate`, we used `FoldList` (like Leonid's answer).  It's like `Accumulate` generalized for operations other than `Plus`.

Comment: @stevenvh `Accumulate` is optimized on packed arrays, which is one of the good reasons to use it in place of `FoldList` for running sums.  In this case, since the `dataacc[[All, 2]]` is not going to be packed at the start, it may improve the performance to pack it first, before the call to `Accumulate`. The resulting list is going to be unpacked during an assignment though, so I don't know how much speed improvement this may bring, if any.

Comment: @Leonid Perhaps the dates can be converted to AbsoluteTime format.  Then we can keep everything packed.

Comment: @Szabolcs The question is, how time-consuming would that be as compared to what `Accumulate` or `FoldList` have to do. Adding integers is supposedly a much faster operation than date conversion.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an arguably functional-style version without in-place modifications:

```
FoldList[{First@#2, #2[[2]] + #1[[2]]} &, First@data, Rest@data]
```

It is likely to be slower than the solution proposed by Szabolcs.

Answer (score 5):

Another one!

```
val = data[[All, 2]];
Transpose@{data[[All, 1]], Take[FoldList[Plus, 0, val], -Length@val]}
```

Comment: I've thought of the `Transpose` + `Take` too, but I'm not sure it will be the fastest. I'll benchmark the different answers later and report back. In any case, thanks.