# Why does taking advantage of Listable change the results of a numerical computation slightly?

Tags: numerics

I have two variables: `t0`, and `teta0`. The first is computed using several nested sums, the second is computed taking advantage to some listable properties of some functions. Both should return the same, when using the same data/sample.

For a small random sample size (e.g. 10) the difference between them is of the order of 10^-15 or 10^-16 or 0, and when I do `t0==teta0` I get `True`. 
When I increase the sample size (e.g. 999), the difference between them is sometimes of the same magnitude. But when I do `t0==teta0` I get `False`.

Here is the code:

```
n = 999;

Tauijk = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {2, n}];

y = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {1, n + 1}][[1]];
one = ConstantArray[1, n];

teta0 = (Plus @@ 
     Flatten[(Tauijk.y[[2 ;; n + 1]])*(Tauijk*{y[[1 ;; n]], 
           y[[1 ;; n]]})*(Tauijk.one)^(-1) - (Tauijk*{y[[
           2 ;; n + 1]], y[[2 ;; n + 1]]}*{y[[1 ;; n]], 
          y[[1 ;; n]]})])/(Plus @@ 
     Flatten[(Tauijk.y[[1 ;; n]])*(Tauijk*{y[[1 ;; n]], 
           y[[1 ;; n]]})*(Tauijk.one)^(-1) - (Tauijk*{y[[
           1 ;; n]], y[[1 ;; n]]}*{y[[1 ;; n]], y[[1 ;; n]]})]);


t0 = (Sum[
     Sum[(Sum[y[[j + 1]]*Tauijk[[i, j]], {j, 1, n}])*Tauijk[[i, 
         k]]*y[[k]]/(Sum[Tauijk[[i, j]], {j, 1, n}]) - 
       y[[k + 1]]*y[[k]]*Tauijk[[i, k]], {i, 1, 2}], {k, 1, 
      n}])/(Sum[
     Sum[(Sum[
           y[[j]]*Tauijk[[i, j]], {j, 1, 
            n}]/(Sum[Tauijk[[i, j]], {j, 1, n}]) - 
         y[[k]])*Tauijk[[i, k]]*y[[k]], {i, 1, 2}], {k, 1, n}]);
```

This is strange because when I try something similar with some two other simpler variables like

```
 teta1 = (Plus @@ 
     Flatten[Tauijk[[1, 
        1 ;; n]]*(y[[2 ;; n + 1]] - teta0*y[[1 ;; n]])])/(Plus @@ 
     Flatten[Tauijk[[1, 1 ;; n]]]);

t1 = Sum[Tauijk[[1, j]]*(y[[j + 1]] - teta0*y[[j]]), {j, 1, n}]/
   Sum[Tauijk[[1, j]], {j, 1, n}];
```

I get the same order of magnitude for the difference as I would get for `t0-teta0` and when doing `t1==teta1`, I get `True`. I simply cannot understand why this happens.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without digging into details, this is almost certainly related to machine precision limitations, and rounding in machine precision. `$MachinePrecision` is about 16, which means rounding occurs at that resolution (in practice, 53 bits). You can work in higher precision by using `WorkingPrecision` option in `RandomReal`.

Comment: @kirma Is there a way to set globally the machine precision at higher values?

Comment: By checking that all reals in your computations are arbitrary-precision numbers (which `WorkingPrecision` does in this case, and for explicit numbers backtick like 1.5`20), numerical computations are performed in arbitrary-precision arithmetic. This is a bit different from machine precision, which is directly based on hardwired implementation on the CPU. This is a slightly convoluted topic to understand correctly; I suggest looking at the documentation on (arbitrary) precision and questions on [tag:precision] and [tag:arbitrary-precision].

Comment: @kirma Many Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you work with machine numbers the precision depends on the order of summation. The built-in functions `Plus` and `Total` are more intelligent then straightforward summation. It can be shown by the following example

```
x = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, {10000}]/RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {10000}];
res = Accumulate[x];
nx = N[x];
s[n_] := Sum[nx[[k]], {k, 1, n}];
p[n_] := Plus @@ nx[[;; n]];
tc[n_] := Total[nx[[;; n]], Method -> "CompensatedSummation"];

r = Range[1, 10000, 10];

ListLinePlot[{s /@ r - res[[r]], p /@ r - res[[r]], tc /@ r - res[[r]]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Sum/Accumulate", "Plus/Total", "Total with compensation"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't know about `Method -> "CompensatedSummation"` - thanks, +1!

Comment: This answer (which I upvoted, of course) is a nice illustration of what I was going to put in a comment (and will still do so now): finite precision addition is not associative.

Comment: But exactly what *is* "compensated summation"?? Is it what's described in https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/517618/filename/Yong-KangZhu2005b.pdf ?

Comment: @murray, it's a nice floating point trick due to Velvel Kahan. Search around; this is in fact a very well-studied procedure.

Comment: @J.M. related [(79174)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79174/compilation-of-total-with-compensatedsummation/)