# Total much slower in version 10

Tags: version-10, performance-tuning

**Issue introduced in version 10, fixed in 10.0.2**

---

Compilation nowadays may give very fast functions. Here is an example for finding the sum of a list of machine numbers, just as the built-in function `Total`:

```
myTotal =   Compile[{{lst, _Real, 1}}, 
  Module[{s = 0.}, Do[s = s + x, {x, lst}]; s], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C"];

lst = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^7}];
myTotal[lst] == Total[lst]
(*True *)
```

In Mathematica 10, I noted the surprising fact that the function myTotal is more than three times as fast as `Total`:

```
Do[myTotal[lst], {500}] // Timing (* {4.758031, Null} *)
Do[Total[lst], {500}] // Timing (* {16.052503, Null} *)
```

In Mathematica 9, they are as fast. So in Mathematica 10 (on Windows), Total is more than 3 times slower than in Mathematica 9, fortunately of course still very fast. What could be the reason for this slowdown?

Comment: It's a known issue, reported and under investigation.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Is it at this point decided whether there'll be a 10.0.2?  Or was 10.0.1 the last 10.0.x version?

Comment: There are so many slow-downs in M10 that there have to me more bug-fix releases. I just go on mostly with V9 for the time being. Groetjes, Rolf

Comment: Just a comment that if you're trying, in effect, to average the summation over `10^7` random reals, would it not make more sense to use `ls := RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^2}]`, that is, with a `SetDelayed`?

Comment: @Murray. I wanted to compare 500 evaluations of both myTotal and Total on the same list. With SetDelayed, I would have got 1000 different lists, and moreover the time needed for constructing these lists would be included in the Timings.

Comment: @Szabolcs I believe there will be a 10.0.2 but my beliefs sometimes depart from the real world.

Comment: Just a note, `Total` is [more precise then the direct summation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/62929/4678).

Comment: @Fred Simons: Understood why you wanted to use very same list for all 500 evaluations. I suggested varying the list just to eliminate anything special about the particular list of random numbers you might generate.

Comment: I tested that in v.10.0.2 (OS X 10.9.5) : `Total` is now as fast as `myTotal`.

Answer (score 11):

Until this issue gets fixed by WRI you can use [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr.html?q=Tr) instead of `Total`

```
Do[myTotal[lst], {500}] // Timing
Do[Total[lst], {500}] // Timing 
Do[Tr[lst], {500}] // Timing
```

> ```
> {5.241634, Null}  
> {16.161704, Null}  
> {5.194833, Null}
> ```

```
myTotal[lst] == Total[lst] == Tr[lst]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: `Tr` has the same precision as "Plus/Total" in [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/62929/18476](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/62929/18476)