# Is there a more elegant way to write this statement?

Tags: programming, code-review

```
Total[TakeWhile[Map[#^3 &, Range[1, 200]], # < 10000 &]]
```

Comment: Could you also explain in words what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: `Total@Select[Range[200]^3, # < 10000 &]`

Comment: we apply (ˆ3) to an infinite list (sorry, I do not know how to write an infinite list, so I wrote a big number 200). and then once an element that;s over 100000 is encountered, the list is cut off. Finally, we sum it up

Comment: `Total @ TakeWhile[ Range[ 200 ]^3, LessThan[ 10000 ] ]` looks decent.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli `Select` only works here because the list ist ordered, but in general is not the same as `TakeWhile`...

Comment: Hi gwr, thank you for your help. I would like to ask when we can use "@" after a function. For instance, The function "Total" followed by a "@". I understand it means we apply the list to the "Total". How can we do t the same thing to the TakeWhile. The problem is that TakeWhile needs two arguments.

Comment: @gwr Good point! Thanks!

Comment: @bios: `f@x` basically means the same as `f[x]`, it's just a shorthand. Here's a great overview: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616

Answer (score 20):

```
Total[Range[CubeRoot[10000]]^3]
```

> 53361

Comment: Actually `Tr[Range[CubeRoot[10000]]^3]` as @Kuba had written is faster.

Comment: @gwr: I see no measurable difference. I'm almost certain they end up calling the same low-level functions. But if you want speed, use `Total[Range[CubeRoot[10000.]]^3]` (notice the `.` after the 10000) or `Total[Range[CubeRoot[N[10000]]]^3]` - that way the whole calculation is done in machine precision floating point numbers, which is faster by an order of magnitude.

Comment: Use `RepeatedTiming` and a sufficiently large number. The difference also is detectable when using machine precision.

Comment: @gwr: What is sufficiently large? I've tried 60s, and I see no difference. Have you tried repeating your measurement?

Comment: @gwr The performance of `Tr` vs. `Total` [is version dependent](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63209/total-much-slower-in-version-10/63282#63282). I don't see a difference: [screen snippet](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wRw5p.png)

Comment: @Karsten7. Ok, it may be *too close to call*: [screen snippet](http://imgur.com/a/6xfqm) :)

Comment: Slight alternative: `Sum[i^3 , {i, 1, CubeRoot[10000]}]`

Comment: @gwr Just change the order and `Total` will look better than `Tr` ;)

Answer (score 8):

I like compositions for readability, thus:

```
Range[200] // RightComposition[
  # ^ 3 &,
  TakeWhile[#, LessThan @ 10000] &,
  Total
  ]
```

> 53361

Using [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) also works (here in infix form):

```
Total @* (TakeWhile[ #, LessThan@10000] &) @ (Range[200]^3)
```

Note, that using `Composition` in its infix form reveals somen tricky precendence issues. Thus use `expr // Defer // FullForm` and compare what happens if parantheses are dropped and if Superscript-Power-notation is used rather than `^3`...

Comment: This is the most satisfactory answer so far.

Comment: @bios you can reflect that by upvoting (gray triangle next to the answer)

Comment: It may be *old fashioned* to not write everything as a one liner, but this form allows for putting a comment behind every function telling what is going on as it gets a separate line. After all, humans are a special form of parser...

Answer (score 5):

```
NestWhile[{#[[1]] + 1, #[[1]]^3, #[[2]] + #[[3]]} &, {1, 0, 0}, #[[2]] < 10000 &] // Last
```

> `53361`

Comment: Why not `NestWhile[{#1 + 1, #1^3, #2 + #3} & @@ # &, {1, 0, 0}, #[[2]] < 10000 &] // Last`?

Comment: Nice making use of functional programming - albeit not very readable for humans imo. :)

Comment: @ShutaoTang Why `Slot` and `Apply` instead of `Part`?

Comment: @gwr That's subjective.

Comment: Most certainly it is. But I would bet that having people with different backgrounds in computing vote on it would reveal a majority on my side of the argument. (cf. my comment on [my own answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124037/764))

Comment: @Karsten7. In my opinion, that way could improve readability of code:)

Comment: @ShutaoTang It looks much nicer in the FrontEnd using matching double brackets [screen snippet](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rCFrJ.png). I'm just not a big fan of extra `@@ # &`.

Answer (score 5):

Why are people not making use of listability?

```
Total[Range[Floor[1*^4^(1/3)]]^3]
```

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? I agree it's similar to @nikie's but, there are many similar ones here.

Comment: `Floor` should be redundant and then it IS @nikie's answer?

Answer (score 4):

Or like this:

```
Map[#^3 &, Range[1, Floor[10000 ^(1/3)]]]

Total[%]
(*53361*)
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you'll beat

```
(# (# + 1)/2)^2& @ Floor[CubeRoot[10000]]
```

for speed.  It did require some thought though.

Answer (score 4):

Going for variety more than elegance here:

```
{0, 0} //. {{x_, y_} :> {x + y^3, y + 1} /; y^3 < 10000, {x_, _} :> x}
(* 53361 *)

If[#2^3 < 10000, #0[#1 + #2^3, #2 + 1], #1] &[0, 0]
(* 53361 *)

1 ~Range~ 200 ~Power~ 3 ~TakeWhile~ LessThan@10000 ~Total~ 1
(* 53361 *)
```