# List interpolation

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation, series-expansion

Hi mathematica people!

So i am looking for the best way to interpolate a function given a list of its values. I have an iterative algorithm which needs high precision otherwise the numerical noise is going to increase exponentially. It works like this(not the exact code, but just to illustrate):

```
Nmax := 10;
Tmax := 1000;
K[t_, s_] := s^2 (PolyGamma[2, 1 - (t-s)] - 0.5 PolyGamma[2, 1 - (t-s)/2])

Table[{t, NIntegrate[ K[t,s] (PolyGamma[1, 1 - 2 I s] - 0.5 PolyGamma[1, 1 - I s]) ,{s, 0, t-1} ]}, {t, 1, Tmax} ]
f[0]:= Interpolation[ %, InterpolationOrder -> 1 ];

For[ i = 1 , i < Nmax , i++ , 
Table[{t, NIntegrate[ K[t,s] f[i][s] ,{s, 0, t-1} ]}, {t, 1, Tmax} ];
f[i+1] := Interpolation[ %, InterpolationOrder -> 1 ]; 
]
```

The problem with this is that each function f[i] is coming from integrating f[i-1], so errors are going to be multiplied and enhanced. Is there a better way to integrate numerical interpolation? Or perhaps a better way to interpolate?

In the end i am interested in obtaining a plot of

```
f := Sum[ f[i] , {i , 0 , Nmax } ]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful :) With Method -> InterpolationPointsSubdivision i could avoid the convergence failure error.

Answer (score 1):

Some points:

1. You are integrating a function of `InterpolatingFunction`. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18863/280) thread for guidance how to achieve maximum precision in this situation using `NIntegrate`.
2. You are using `Sum` for summing up imprecise numbers which is the worst way to do this as demonstrated [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/62929/280). Use `Total` with option `"CompensatedSummation" -> True` instead.
3. Avoid using explicit loops and use functional programming instead. This point is discussed in details [in many places](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22functional%20programming%22) on this site. In particular, I recommend reading these threads:

   [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/280)

   [Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/280)