# Incorrect Timing of Total

Tags: windows, timing, version-10.3

For demonstrating how fast C-compiled functions can be, in one of my courses I use the following function for finding the sum of a list of reals:

```
myTotal = Compile[{{lst, _Real, 1}},Module[{s=0.}, Do[s=s+z, {z, lst}];s], CompilationTarget->"C"];
```

In Mathematica 8 and 9, this function is about as fast as the built-in function `Total`.

In Mathematica 10.0.0, there was a minor bug in `Total`, making `Total` three times slower than `myTotal`. That bug is repaired now. Even better, while the function `myTotal` is as fast as it was, `Total` now is almost two times faster:

```
lst=RandomReal[{0,1}, {2 10^7}];

Do[myTotal[lst], {100}] // RepeatedTiming
Do[Total[lst], {100}] // RepeatedTiming

(* {1.919,Null}
   {1.05,Null} *)
```

`RepeatedTiming` works fine. However, in Mathematica 10.3, `Timing` for `Total` does not work well:

```
Do[myTotal[lst], {100}] // Timing
Do[Total[lst], {100}] // Timing

(* {1.93441,Null}
   {0.,Null} *)

Do[myTotal[lst], {100}] // AbsoluteTiming
Do[Total[lst], {100}] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {1.92955,Null}
   {1.05932,Null} *)

Do[Total[lst], {1000}] // Timing

(* {0.0312002,Null} *)
```

This looks like a minor bug to me. Is this bug restricted to Windows, or is it a 'general' bug?

Comment: I can reproduce it on Windows, but not on OS X.  It is indeed specific to `Total`.  Tagging it as bug.

Comment: This is not specific to `Total`. For example, `Do[Exp[lst];, {50}] // Timing` returns `{0., Null}`, whereas `Do[Exp[lst];, {50}] // AbsoluteTiming` returns `{2.14685, Null}` on my PC with Win 10 and Mma 10.3.

Comment: I normally never use `Timing`, as I consider it meaningless. Or as the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Timing.html) puts it: "it may ..." and "on some operating systems ...".

Comment: @Karsten7. `Timing` was originally meant to measure total CPU time in the main kernel process. It is far from meaningless in principle, and if it worked reliably, it would probably be more broadly useful than `AbsoluteTiming`. But, I agree that more effort needs to be spent to make its operation reliable and consistent enough to trust it.

Comment: `Do[Total[lst], {1000}]; // Timing // AbsoluteTiming` returns `{10.0118, {0.046875, Null}}`. Probably most of the calculation is just done in a way that "on some operating systems, `Timing` may ignore".

Comment: By the way, `Total` is [more intelligent](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/62929/4678) then the direct sum.

Comment: Why is this considered a bug? [`Timing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Timing.html) behaves as documented. It's just not necessarily the timing function one would like to have.

Comment: @Karsten7. agreed; it shouldn't be a bug. I'll remove the tag. I would still argue strongly against this being a useful implementation of `Timing`, though. In the past the problem wasn't obvious because few functions were multithreaded. Now, as the rest of *Mathematica* improves, `Timing` is becoming increasingly useless.

Comment: @ybeltukov so is rolling your own function! http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79174/compilation-of-total-with-compensated-summation?lq=1

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14152/1871

Answer (score 13):

There are a couple of issues at play.

One is that the implementation of `Total` has changed, and it is now using several threads in parallel.

Furthermore, there are platform-specific differences in how `Timing` works. On Windows, it will only measure the CPU time used by the main kernel thread, excluding any subthreads. On Linux, and I believe OS X, it will include all threads in the kernel process.

As mentioned in the documentation,

> On certain computer systems with multiple CPUs, the Wolfram Language kernel may sometimes spawn additional threads on different CPUs. On some operating systems, [`Timing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Timing.html) may ignore these additional threads. On other operating systems, it may give the total time spent in all threads, which may exceed the result from [`AbsoluteTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html).

Comment: How can one find out that a function like `Total` is using several threads? Its only attribute is `Protected`.  Can I implant some ``Developer`ThreadID[]`` into the evaluation somehow?

Comment: @Karsten7. No top level interface for this, it's a pthread-level API. Your OS should however have tools to monitor threads as they are being launched, their resource usage etc.

Comment: Would it not be possible to fix the Windows implementation so that it takes all threads into account (like the Task Manager does)? I appreciate that the documentation technically allows for this behavior, but from a usefulness point of view, it's very unhelpful (in my opinion). Not considering separate processes is, however, absolutely fine (again, IMO).

Comment: Has the implementation of compensated summation changed at all in 10.3? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79174/compilation-of-total-with-compensated-summation/79194#79194

Comment: @OleksandrR. Yes, developers are aware of this in principle. It would be nice to have consistency between platforms and taking all threads in account seems more useful to me, though presumably there could be arguments for the other side too.

Comment: @blochwave Not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 7):

This is just a comment with code. Here is a very simple multithreaded compiled function (not a sum calculation) to prove that the issue has nothing to do with `Total` specifically, but is a more general (and unfortunate) issue with `Timing`:

```
fc = Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}, {n, _Integer, 0}}, 
  Block[{y = x}, Do[y = Tan[y], {n}]; y],
  Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> Listable
 ];

fc[Range[$ProcessorCount], 5*^7] // Timing // AbsoluteTiming
(* -> {1.281250, {0., (* numerical results omitted *) }} *)
```

(Adding `CompilationTarget -> "C"` will make no difference to the result. Although, note that the code has to return something, otherwise many C compilers will eliminate it, resulting in the timing of 0 being absolutely correct.)