# How can I pass arguments to Module without being reinterpreted each time they appear inside it?

Tags: scoping, timing

I'm trying to understand how to save time when calling functions in Mathematica. I wrote this example,

```
mat1 = RandomInteger[{-100, +100}, {200, 200}];  
mat2 = RandomInteger[{-100, +100}, {200, 200}];  
Timing[Inverse[mat1]][[1]]  
matrixOp1[mat_?MatrixQ] := Module[{lm = mat}, lm + mat2]  
Timing[matrixOp1[Inverse[mat1]]][[1]]
matrixOp2[mat_?MatrixQ] := Module[{lm = mat}, lm + lm]
Timing[matrixOp2[Inverse[mat1]]][[1]]
```

I thought that since module uses local vars, `matrixOp2` will work at the same speed as `matrixOp1`. But this is what I found - the output is as such

```
Out[134]= 0.0312002  
Out[136]= 0.0780005  
Out[138]= 0.764405
```

It looks to me like the Inverse operation occurs many times inside `matrixOp2` and I don't understand why. Can anyone please explain?

Thanks
Tamir

Comment: Have you tried using `TracePrint[]` on your functions?

Comment: what do you mean `Inverse` operation happens many times? Result of `Inverse` goes in `matrixOp2`. I believe it has to do with implementation of `Module`. There could be a call to create a new context and copy information in there before proceeding and switching to old context after processing. This could be the reason for delay.

Comment: The slow down is due to `+` using the new allocated matrix `lm` in Module context.  You can see this by changing `Module[{lm = mat}, lm + lm]` to `Module[{lm = 2*mat}, lm ]` which is the same thing, but now its speed is similar to the second case where the `+` with with the global mat.  So the slow down happens to due to adding, element by element, `lm` to `lm` in the module content. It should not really be this much slower. This is strange. With compiled languages, the compiler will see this and will do this at compile time!

Comment: @Nasser : I don't think that correctly answers the question because in that case `lm+mat2` and `lm+lm` should take same time, but it doesn't. In both cases, it is element by element addition.

Comment: @Rorschach first of all, I was not answering, just giving an observation. But there is a difference between `lm+mat2` and `lm+lm`. In one case `mat2` is global, while in the second case it is local. There could be difference there in how and/or where each is allocated, or some overhead to access local module level heap. But not knowing internals of Mathematica, this is all speculation.

Comment: @Nasser : I understand that its an observation, I should have chosen my words carefully. In my opinion this `local` is nothing but a new temporary context, but then it can only be a guess.

Comment: @Nasser, I think you missed that `mat2` is integers while `lm` is rationals. The comparison between `lm + mat2` and `lm + lm` is not fair - it's a different arithmetic problem.

Comment: @SimonWoods yes! I definitely missed that they are different types. This explains the difference in performance.

Answer (score 6):

Fred's answer explains why `Timing` is a poor indicator of how much internal computation is taking place. This is an extended comment to point out that the real timing differences you see are just due to the different arithmetic problem in each case.

Note that the inverse of your integer matrix is a matrix of rationals with large numerators and denominators. *Mathematica* can add integer + rational faster than it can add rational + rational. Here's a simplified version of your code without any Modules:

```
lm = Inverse @ RandomInteger[{-100, +100}, {200, 200}];
mat2 = RandomInteger[{-100, +100}, {200, 200}];

AbsoluteTiming[lm + mat2][[1]]
(* 0.0290076 *)

AbsoluteTiming[lm + lm][[1]]
(* 1.12371 *)
```

So you can see that the difference between `matrixOp1` and `matrixOp2` is nothing to do with global vs local symbols, but simply that `matrixOp1` is doing a faster operation (adding rationals and integers) than `matrixOp2` (adding rationals and rationals)

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that your results have to do more with strange behaviour of `Timing` than with `Module`. See the answers on my question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98453/20253) for more information. In absolute timings, the results are as expected. I included also Nasser's modification.

Here are the definitions:

```
mat1=RandomInteger[{-100,+100},{200,200}];
mat2=RandomInteger[{-100,+100},{200,200}];
matrixOp1[mat_?MatrixQ]:=Module[{lm=mat},lm+mat2]
matrixOp2[mat_?MatrixQ]:=Module[{lm=mat},lm+lm]
matrixOp3[mat_?MatrixQ]:=Module[{lm=mat},2 lm]
```

And here my results:

```
Timing[Inverse[mat1]][[1]]// AbsoluteTiming
(* {5.65742,0.0312002} *)

Timing[matrixOp1[Inverse[mat1]]][[1]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {5.71078,0.0624004} *)

Timing[matrixOp2[Inverse[mat1]]][[1]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {7.002,1.37281} *)

Timing[matrixOp3[Inverse[mat1]]][[1]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {5.83677,0.109201} *)
```

The big difference between `Timing` and `AbsoluteTiming` is at least remarkable.