# Summation over list elements

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

As we know, one of the simplest way to do a summation (with special intervals) over list elements is using

```
Sum[list[[i]], {i, 3, 8, 2 }] (*with steps of 2*)
```

for a list such as `list={a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l}` which returns `c + e + g`.

How can we use `Replacelist` or `FoldList` to this aim?

I am learning important functions (FoldList and ReplaceList) which are used instead of (Accumulation) in [sum over list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23677/how-to-sum-over-a-list), in which I faced to some problems and could not find correct things. Instead of accumulation, for a simple summation what does it work!?

Comment: Why would you want to use a likely less efficient mechanism like `ReplaceList` or `FoldList` for this  than what you've shown, or better yet, `Tr@list[[3;;8;;2]]`? Is this going to be a moving-goal-post question, and there's really something more complex you want to accomplish, or are you just looking for slower ways?

Comment: @ciao You're starting to mind-read. Beware of what you find :)

Comment: "...you allow yourself to insult me...", huh? I have no idea what you're talking about. If I'd wanted to insult you (and I don't, no reason to and this is not the place for such nonsense in any case), I'd invite you to a chat room for a lashing...

Comment: If I made mistake I do apologize, I am so sorry. Please pardon me,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd allow myself some guesswork here, that you're going after alternatives as a form of excercise in Mathematica programming. However, you've clearly stated, that the list is

```
list={a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l}
```

and the expected output is

```
c + e + g
```

Note, that in the question you've linked, `ReplaceList` and `FoldList` are utilized to generate *lists* of results, analogous to `Accumulate`. But even then, the functions used in the replacement rules or passed as arguments to `FoldList` are the conventional `Plus`. In this question, only a single expression is expected.

Off the top of my head I can only come up with this improvement to your code:

```
Total@list[[3;;8;;2]]
(* c + e + g *)
```

Comment: …and before `Span[]` became built-in, one used `Take[]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. *`m[[i;;j;;k]]` is equivalent to `Take[m,{i,j,k}]`.* Interesting. I like to compare the `FullForm`s: `Part[list, Span[3, 8, 2]]` or `Take[list, List[3, 8, 2]]`. They might as well have used a short form for `Take`. Can you say something regarding the performance of either function?

Comment: Not really much I can say ; to be honest, I tend to use `Take[]` more than `Span[]` as a force of habit.