# How to get Sum of array of integers?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, summation, list-manipulation

This question seems easy but I am struggling with it now, I tried a few ways and check this [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23677/how-to-sum-over-a-list) as well but couldn't help me, please check and help if you are able:
So I need to save the sum of array elements in single variable and I tried these approaches, I show you two of them here. (**I must have x as variable to store result, and initialize the array as well**)

```
Array [A, 3]
A = {1, 2, 5}
R2 = x == Sum[A[index], {index, i, 3}]  && i == 1
Simplify[Reduce[R2]]
```

And Also

```
R2 = x == Sum[A[index], {index, i, 3}] && A[1] == 1 && A[2] == 2 && A[3] == 5 && i == 1
Simplify[Reduce[R2]]
```

this is part of final answer I get

```
x == A[1] + A[2] + A[3]
```

It shows me a simple equation not final answer, but I expect a simple answer **x== 8 or x-> 8**, but it does not solve the SUM, seems I am missing something.

EDITED:
based on @thorimur answer I completed my question.
Actually the reason i used Reduce and Sum is:
1- I used reduce because we have more complicated expressions which Sum is part of that.
2- I used sum because not all the time we have initialized array. For some times, i need parametric array which must be shown in Sum. this is the more complete statement.

```
R2 = x == Sum[A[index], {index, i, 3}]  && i == 1
R3=Simplify[Reduce[
  Exists[{i,x,A},  R2 && // Array initialization // i == 1 ]]]
```

I know this does not work but this is my intention. we need a statement as R3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things:

- Mathematica generally doesn't require you to initialize arrays before constructing them or anything like that; you can just construct them! `Array[A, 3]` does not give any definitions to the variable `A`; it merely outputs `{A[1], A[2], A[3]}` without changing any variables. Only the next line does anything to affect the symbol `A`, and it defines `A` as `{1,2,5}`.
- Single-brackets are for function application. So, in the above `Sum`, it expects `A` to be a function that takes in `index`. To access parts of a list, use double brackets. E.g. with `A = {1,2,5}`, `A[[3]]` evaluates to `5`.
- `Sum` is typically used for mathematical sums, like $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$, which would simply be written as `Sum[1/n^2, {n, 1, Infinity}]`. In the above, you could have simply replaced `i` with its value. It's not used for adding up elements of lists, generally.
- `Reduce` is essentially for solving equations, like `Reduce[x^2 == 1, x]`—you wouldn't expect to use `Reduce` in manipulating data structures, like you want to do here.
- Note that the solution you linked is about getting a list of *successive* sums, not simply adding up the elements of the list! The function `Total` is used for that.

So, the following is sufficient:

```
A = {1, 2, 5}
x = Total[A]
```

There are also several ways to add up a range of indices but not all of them. One of them is indeed `Sum[A[[index]], {index, indexmin, indexmax}]`, but you could also simply do `Total[A[[indexmin ;; indexmax]]]`; `;;` specifies a span of indices (inclusive). So, for example, if `A = {1,2,5}`, `A[[2;;3]]` evaluates to `{2,5}`.

Also, if you have a list of indices—say you want to add up the elements at indices `indexlist = {2, 4, 8}`—you can simply feed a whole list to `[[ ]]` and get out a list of the elements at those indices, then apply `Total`. E.g. `indexlist = {2, 4, 8}`, `A[[indexlist]]` gets you `{A[[2]], A[[4]], A[[8]]}`. Then you can `Total` that list.

To create a symbolic array, though, you'll want to be sure to give your array and its components different names. For example, `A0 = Array[A, 3]`. Note that `A0[[i]]` now evaluates to `A[i]`. I'm still not totally sure what you need, but note that you might not need to do any initialization at all. I could write `Sum[A[i], {i, 1, 3}]` and get `A[1] + A[2] + A[3]` without needing to define an array `A0` of these `A` anywhere. Mathematica's symbolic nature is a strength here.

Hope this helps; let me know if it doesn't quite get you where you need to be, or if anything I said is unclear! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind response, the reason I used Reduce is that, I have more complicated expressions which Sum is just part of that. for some statements, i have a parametric array . so we used SUM. please see my edited as it gets long here. thanks

Comment: can we rewrite Total with Sum, I might need to get sum of a range of indices not all, thanks

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean by parametric array, but I added a couple ways to extract and total sublists of lists! I don't quite know what your added code does, though. (I'm also not sure why we're multiplying and dividing by `1` at various places)

Comment: Ah, wait, I think I understand. I think that would typically be called a symbolic array in Mathematica!

Comment: added another potential section, but I'm still not sure it addresses what you need. Let me know if it doesn't! (I might need a fuller description of what problem you're actually trying to solve.)

Comment: Sum[A3[[index]], {index, i, 3}] && i == 1  this does not work but Sum[A3[[index]], {index, 1, 3}] works.

Comment: I edited my post, there is what i need , thanks again.

Comment: I just checked that Total does not work with span, Total[A[2;;3]] and also the symbolic array doesnt give me something meaningful. btw thanks.

Comment: span uses the same syntax as `Part`: two brackets, not one. `Total[A[[2 ;; 3]] ]`